# Where do the App Engine service account (gserviceaccount) emails go?

Tags: google-app-engine

In the App Engine "`Application Settings`" page it lists an email address:

```
mocktagish@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

If someone sends an email to this address, how do I read it?

What do I need this address for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is an email address. This is the service account name, an external identifier for your application.

The settings page says:

> Use this name when interacting with external services on behalf of
>   your application.

You use it e.g. while connecting your app to Google Cloud Storage.