# Can't backup GAE application datastore to GS bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm trying to backup GAE datastore to GS bucket as described here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Backup_And_Restore. I've tried to supply bucket name in forms:

```
bucket 
/gs/bucket
/gs/bucket/path
```

but non of it work.
Every time I get a message:

```
There was a problem kicking some off the jobs/tasks:
Invalid bucket name: 'bucket'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible at all to backup all data (including blob files) to GS without writing custom code for this?

Answer (score 21):

I got it to work by adding the service account e-mail as a privileged user with write permission.

Here's what I did:

1. Create bucket via web interface (STORAGE>CLOUD STORAGE>Storage Browser > New Bucket)
2. Add APPID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as a privileged user with edit permission (Permissions>Add Member)

Even thought it was part of the same project, for some reason I still had to add the project e-mail as a privileged user.

Comment: This worked for me as well, in the new Google Cloud console. Thanks!

Comment: No "s~" on the app ID. If your app ID is "s~myapp", use "myapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"

Comment: This **still** isn't mentioned in the Google Docs, at least not that I've found.

Comment: OMG thank you! Wasted so much time on that. I have 2 apps, same setup (I thought) and one worked and one didn't, drove me crazy.

Comment: Great job! You should add that the step 2. need to be done in IAM&ADMIN and I needed to define the bucket as /gs/bucket

Comment: This is incredibly arcane, basically a magic spell you have to cast. How anyone could figure this out without stackoverflow is beyond me.

Comment: Found myself coming back to this question. Remember to use project-hrd@appspot.gserviceaccount.com if you've upgraded to HRD at some point. Haven't tested, but looks like you can also create buckets and give them privileges on command line with "gsutil mb gs://bucket-name" "gsutil acl ch -u something@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://bucket-name"

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the bucket does not exist or else app engine does not have permission to write to the bucket.

Make sure the following are true:

1. You have created `BUCKET`. Use something like [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil#gettingstarted) to create the bucket if necessary.

   - `gsutil mb gs://BUCKET`
2. Make sure your app engine service account has WRITE access to `BUCKET`.

   - The [service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779925/where-do-the-app-engine-service-account-gserviceaccount-emails-go) is of the form `APP_NAME`@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
   - Add the service account to your [project team](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?#:team) with `can edit` access.
   - Alternatively you can [change the bucket acl](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#About-Access-Control-Lists) and the service account there. This option is more complicated.
3. Now start the backup using the form `/gs/BUCKET`

If you get an `Bucket "/gs/BUCKET" is not accessible` message then your bucket does not exist, or `APP_NAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` does not have access to your bucket.

NOTE: the form is `/gs/BUCKET`. The following are wrong: *BUCKET*, *gs://BUCKET*, *gs/BUCKET* etc.

Check that the bucket exists with the right permissions with following command:

```
gsutil getacl gs://BUCKET  # Note the URI form here instead of a path.
```

Look for an entry like the following:

```
<Entry>
  <Scope type="UserByEmail">
    <EmailAddress>APP_NAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com</EmailAddress>
  </Scope>
  <Permission>WRITE</Permission>
</Entry>
```

If you don't see one you can add one in the following manner:

```
gsutil getacl gs://BUCKET > acl.xml
vim acl.xml  # Or your favorite editor
# Add the xml above
gsutil setacl acl.xml gs://BUCKET
```

Now the steps above will work.

Comment: done all of this. actually my app is writing data to that bucket. so its all ok with access rights

Comment: That is surprising. The above steps worked for me. I tried with a new and preexisting bucket. The buckets did not work until I updated the ACL as shown above. I'd suggest trying with a new, throwaway bucket name. For example I used /gs/delete-this-bucket.

Comment: just done everything you have proposed. can see the write permission from gsutil getacl command; everything is in place; same effect

Comment: What is your app and bucket name? What does gsutil getacl output?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a while wrestling with this myself. Thank you @fejta for your assistance.

I could not figure this out. I had added my user to the project, verified that I could write, manually updated the ACL (which should not have been required), ...

In the end, creating a bucket from the command line via:

```
gsutil mb gs://BUCKET
```

instead of the web user interface worked for me. Multiple buckets created either before or after adding the user to the team all resulted in 'Invalid bucket name'

I addressed it with:

```
/gs/BUCKET
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow closely the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring#restoring_data_to_another_app

Things to make sure:

1. add ACL permission to your target application
2. if the backup is already created before adding permission to the bucket, find the backup and add permission
3. add *[PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com* as a member of you source application with Editor role
4. the path to import in your source application is */gs/bucket*